# spark-shell doesn't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I install Spark， I type `spark-shell` in the terminal, but it doesn't work
It shows:

```
Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.**
```

According to the solution I search on this page: http://blog.csdn.net/xiaomin1991222/article/details/50981584, I revised `/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/sprak-class2.cmd` add this code

```
rem Set JAVA_OPTS to be able to load native libraries and to set heap size   
set JAVA_OPTS=%OUR_JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path=%SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH%  -Xms%SPARK_MEM% -Xmx%SPARK_MEM%    -Dscala.usejavacp=true**
```

But, It doesn't work either. My JDK and JRE works normally.

Comment: did you set JAVA_HOME and SCALA_HOME and SPARK_HOME in your classpath?

Comment: yes , my java programs  works well. And the SCALA_HOME and  SPARK _HOME  have  been set in right ways . Is there any  method to test SCALA_HOME and SPARK_HOME

Comment: try going to SPARK_HOME directory and apply `bin/spark-shell`.

Comment: I have  done it earlier but it doesn't work. The same type mistake